# How to cache the mp4 file (media file). Cache video by range

Tags: nginx, caching, mp4

I'm trying to create cache server that will cache the video file (mp4) from the storage server for video streaming faster. But I don't know how to implement the cache for mp4 file because some files are too big to cache. I heard people cache mp4 by range but I dont know how that work. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Could you provide more Information about what for software you want to use on the server side

Comment: Hi,thank for your help. My server side is centos 7, nginx

Comment: Tha tags suggest this isn't about programming. Configuring nginx is off-topic here. When writing your own cache server as an alternative to nginx, how to deal with a range could be on-topic.

Comment: Did you try Slice‑by‑Slice caching by nginx (introduced in nginx 1.9.8): https://www.nginx.com/blog/smart-efficient-byte-range-caching-nginx/